# Future With HTML5 & CSS3

Tags: html, css

How much the HTML5 and CSS3 are going to elevate the *time and effort* used by both designers and developers using their current incarnations? Will it be a child's play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it'll be a child's play...there will be browser quirks and support variations at least at the beginning.

And if it does become child's play to do what we do now, I am sure we will just take things to the next level and find more complex things to do - push towards new limits :)

Comment: "...at least at the beginning." You mean like how 20% of the world still uses a browser (IE6) that hardly supports CSS2 (published in 1998)? :P